Convert class sjmisc_descr to tibble
The sjmisc package provides summary stats. I need it to a column for each summary statistic to a tibble. But instead it does something strange and adds a single column and seemingly sub-columns within that column.
I need the output below to be a tibble with 13 columns:
library(dplyr);library(tibble);library(sjmisc)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(mpg.stats = descr(mpg)) %>%
  dplyr::select(mpg.stats) -> 
  df

str(df)

'data.frame':   32 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ mpg.stats:Classes ‘sjmisc_descr’ and 'data.frame':   32 obs. of  13 variables:
  ..$ var    : chr  "dd" "dd" "dd" "dd" ...
  ..$ type   : chr  "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" ...
  ..$ label  : chr  "dd" "dd" "dd" "dd" ...
  ..$ n      : int  32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 ...
  ..$ NA.prc : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ mean   : num  20.1 20.1 20.1 20.1 20.1 ...
  ..$ sd     : num  6.03 6.03 6.03 6.03 6.03 ...
  ..$ se     : num  1.07 1.07 1.07 1.07 1.07 ...
  ..$ md     : num  19.2 19.2 19.2 19.2 19.2 19.2 19.2 19.2 19.2 19.2 ...
  ..$ trimmed: num  19.7 19.7 19.7 19.7 19.7 ...
  ..$ range  : chr  "23.5 (10.4-33.9)" "23.5 (10.4-33.9)" "23.5 (10.4-33.9)" "23.5 (10.4-33.9)" ...
  ..$ iqr    : num  7.38 7.38 7.38 7.38 7.38 ...
  ..$ skew   : num  0.672 0.672 0.672 0.672 0.672 ...
  ..- attr(*, "print")= chr "txt"
  ..- attr(*, "encoding")= chr "UTF-8"


How about mtcars %>% summarize(mpg.stats = descr(mpg)) %>% tidyr::unnest(mpg.stats)?

mtcars |> with(descr(mpg))
